# SQL split string on second capital or third letter

Tags: sql, postgresql

How could I split text into two parts, where I would like to capture all text before the second capital letter

I have

```
nycTrSeven
nycPkExt
nycAbEchTrn
```

I would like to have output like:

```
nycTr
nycPk
nycAb
```

Is it possible in SQL or is my only hope to use a programming language like Python ?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: Why do you want this? The best place to do this would be while *loading* the data. Doing so in SQL is the worst option - not only is SQL not meant for text processing, but substring operations *prevent* the database from using indexes. SQL is a set-based query language, not a text processing language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL offers [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.5.2.2.12.1.1.1) with [POSIX](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) regular expression syntax: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nWIhMNUS)

```sql
CREATE TABLE tests(example text);
INSERT INTO tests VALUES 
  ('nycTrSeven'),
  ('nycPkExt'),
  ('nycAbEchTrn');

SELECT substring(example from '^(([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){0,1}[^A-Z]*)')
FROM tests;
```

| substring |
| --- |
| nycTr |
| nycPk |
| nycAb |

Or:

```sql
SELECT left(example, regexp_instr(example,'[A-Z]',1,2) -1 ) FROM tests;
```

Taking left side of the example string, up to -1 character from where the second capital letter is

Comment: This is brilliant. I have so much learning to do in SQL, I’m one month into it. Thank you

Comment: On my Postgres regexp_instr function does not exist. I’m running on 11.17

Comment: @Dan it looks like `regexp_instr()` function was [added in PostgreSQL 15.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/15.0/#id-1.11.6.9.5.7), so it's fairly new. Still, the first suggestion [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/66DbBsjT) on version 11.

Comment: What about `SELECT LEFT(example, 5) FROM tests;`? :-)